# Scrape data from html tags which recieve text through ajax using scrapy

Tags: python, html, ajax, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape details about mobiles listed on 'amazon.in' from this link:[here](http://www.amazon.in/Smartphones/b?ie=UTF8&node=1805560031) using scrapy.

Here is my code:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy import Selector
from tars.items import ProductNameItem
import re as r

class Namespider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "flash"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.in"]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Namespider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = [kwargs.get('start_url')]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@id="pagnNextLink"]')), callback="parse_start_url", follow= True),
)

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        titles = hxs.xpath('//li[@class="s-result-item  celwidget "]')

        items = []
        for i in titles:

            item = ProductNameItem()

            #x-paths:
            name_xpath = "div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/a[1]/h2[1]/text()"
            url_xpath = "div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/a[1]/@href"
            price_xpath = "div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/a[1]/span[1]/text()"
            total_reviews_xpath = "div[1]/div[4]/a[1]/text()"

            #data-extraction:
            item["name"] = ' '.join(i.xpath(name_xpath).extract())
            item["url"] = ' '.join(i.xpath(url_xpath).extract())
            item["price"] = ' '.join(i.xpath(price_xpath).extract())
            item["total_reviews"] = ' '.join(i.xpath(total_reviews_xpath).extract())

            #append all data
            items.append(item)


        return(items)
```

The code is working fine but i am not getting any data for **price and total_reviews** fields. I cross checked many times, x-paths are also correct but further i explored that there is something unusual about the 'a' and 'span' tags in those x-paths. The content in these tags is getting loaded using ajax or something like that.
If anyone can just provide some help over how to scrape data from such html tags.

Comment: Your xpaths are basically asking for failure, use class names  etc.. to get what you are after. Also how are we supposed to know what you are trying to and the link you posted goes nowhere

Comment: My bad. Now the link is fine. I tried classes also, till the 'div' tags its getting the data but as soon as i enter into the 'a' tag nothing is returned.

Comment: what three things exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: In the given link, down the page you can see list of mobile phones and multiple pagination links. I am extracting four things about each product: its name, its url, total no. of reviews and price. I am not getting any data for price and total reviews but getting for rest two.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is loaded with ajax calls, your xpath is wrong, the following css selector gets all the reviews:

```
In [13]: response.css("#container a[href*='#customerReviews']::text").extract()
Out[13]: 
[u'9,812',
 u'32',
 u'32',
 u'17,301',
 u'1,408',
 u'99',
 u'9,816',
 u'9,808',
 u'17,298',
 u'91',
 u'91',
 u'8,351',
 u'9,585',
 u'9,808',
 u'10,223',
 u'174',
 u'809',
 u'671',
 u'5,215',
 u'5,215',
 u'1,776',
 u'462',
 u'671',
 u'1,147']
```

The name, price, link and number of reviews are all inside the *divs* with the *s-item-container* class:

```
In [24]: divs = response.css("div.s-item-container")

In [25]: for d in divs:                             
            anchor = d.css("a.a-link-normal.s-access-detail-page.a-text-normal")[0]
            name = anchor.xpath("./h2/@data-attribute").extract_first()
            reviews = d.css("a[href*='#customerReviews']::text").extract_first()
            a = d.css("a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal")[0]
            link = a.xpath("@href").extract_first()
            price = d.css("span.a-size-base.a-color-price.s-price.a-text-bold::text").extract_first()
            print(name, price, reviews, link)
   ....:     
(u'Moto G Plus, 4th Gen (Black, 32 GB)', u'14,999.00', u'9,813', u'http://www.amazon.in/Moto-Plus-4th-Gen-Black/dp/B01DDP7GZK')
(u'Moto G, 4th Gen (Black, 16GB)', u'12,499.00', u'32', u'http://www.amazon.in/Moto-4th-Gen-Black-16GB/dp/B01DDP7YI4')
(u'Moto G, 4th Gen (White, 16GB)', u'12,499.00', u'32', u'http://www.amazon.in/Moto-4th-Gen-White-16GB/dp/B01DDP7GR8')
(u'Lenovo Vibe K4 Note (Black, 16GB)', u'10,999.00', u'17,301', u'http://www.amazon.in/Lenovo-Vibe-K4-Note-Black/dp/B01A11D2U2')
(u'OnePlus 3 (Graphite, 64GB)', u'27,999.00', u'1,408', u'http://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-3-Graphite-64GB/dp/B01DDP7UQ0')
(u'Lenovo Vibe K5 (Gold, 16GB)', u'6,999.00', u'100', u'http://www.amazon.in/Lenovo-Vibe-K5-Gold-16GB/dp/B01DDP7UYC')
(u'Moto G Plus, 4th Gen (White, 32 GB)', u'14,999.00', u'9,821', u'http://www.amazon.in/Moto-Plus-4th-Gen-White/dp/B01DDP85BY')
(u'Moto G Plus, 4th Gen (Black, 16 GB)', u'13,499.00', u'9,819', u'http://www.amazon.in/Moto-Plus-4th-Gen-Black/dp/B01DDP87N0')
(u'Lenovo Vibe K4 Note (White,16GB)', u'10,999.00', u'17,302', u'http://www.amazon.in/Lenovo-Vibe-K4-Note-White/dp/B01BHUN4S6')
(u'Lenovo Vibe K5 (Silver, 16GB)', u'6,999.00', u'107', u'http://www.amazon.in/Lenovo-Vibe-K5-Silver-16GB/dp/B01DDP7D3A')
(u'Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 (Silver, 32GB)', u'11,999.00', u'1,227', u'http://www.amazon.in/Xiaomi-Redmi-Note-Silver-32GB/dp/B01DK5K8WG')
(u'Lenovo Vibe K5 (Grey, 16GB)', u'6,999.00', u'105', u'http://www.amazon.in/Lenovo-Vibe-K5-Grey-16GB/dp/B01DDP7MFE')
(u'OnePlus X (Onyx, 16GB)', u'14,999.00', u'9,585', u'http://www.amazon.in/OnePlus-E1003-X-Onyx-16GB/dp/B016UPKCGU')
(u'Moto G Plus, 4th Gen (White, 16 GB)', u'13,499.00', u'9,819', u'http://www.amazon.in/Moto-Plus-4th-Gen-White/dp/B01DDP85KU')
(u'Coolpad Note 3 (Black, 16GB)', u'8,499.00', u'10,223', u'http://www.amazon.in/Coolpad-Note-3-Black-16GB/dp/B0158IT7ES')
(u'Intex Aqua Speed HD (White-Champagne, 8GB)', u'4,190.00', u'174', u'http://www.amazon.in/Intex-Aqua-Speed-HD-White-Champagne/dp/B01FD7QTEK')
(u'Asus Zenfone Max ZC550KL-6A068IN (Black, 2GB, 16GB)', u'8,999.00', u'810', u'http://www.amazon.in/Asus-Zenfone-ZC550KL-6A068IN-Black-16GB/dp/B018VKZPG4')
(u'Coolpad Note 3 Plus (Champagne-White)', u'8,999.00', u'670', u'http://www.amazon.in/Coolpad-Note-3-Plus-Champagne-White/dp/B01DDP7V7S')
(u'Redmi 2 (White)', u'5,999.00', u'5,215', u'http://www.amazon.in/Mi-Redmi-2-White/dp/B00VEB055E')
(u'Lenovo Vibe X3 (White, 32GB)', u'19,999.00', u'1,776', u'http://www.amazon.in/Lenovo-Vibe-X3-White-32GB/dp/B01AY3H9QA')
(u'XOLO Era X (Black)', u'10,000.00', u'462', u'http://www.amazon.in/XOLO-ERA-X-Era-Black/dp/B01BWL1A0O')
(u'Coolpad Note 3 Plus (Gold)', u'8,999.00', u'671', u'http://www.amazon.in/Coolpad-Note-3-Plus-Gold/dp/B01DDP7DK8')
(u'HTC Desire 620G (Santroni White)', u'8,699.00', u'1,147', u'http://www.amazon.in/HTC-Desire-620G-Santroni-White/dp/B00R7FPSDU')
(u'Samsung Tizen Z3 (Silver)', u'5,590.00', u'9', u'http://www.amazon.in/Samsung-Tizen-Z3-Silver/dp/B01CXXJ8UY')
```

Always try to use class names, attributes etc.. to find your content, also if you want to test xpaths do it in a scrapy shell not in your browser.

Comment: I actually verified x-paths step by step but still ended up wrong. A lesson learned, would always use classes for x-paths from now. thanks a lot for your help and suggestions.

Comment: @ShubhamPandey, even if they happened to work  using  xpaths like yours would break very easily, there is a lot more chance of a div getting moved around than , ids, class names changing etc...